# Shell Script - Read line from file and do substring with special characters

Tags: shell, substring, special-characters

Reading a txt file i loop every line to insert ';' char at secific position but i have error due to the presence of special characters.

I tried

```
        while read -r line; do
         if [[ $line ==  62* ]]; then         
           newLine="${line:0:2};${line:2:7};${line:9:12};${line:22:10};${line:32:16};${line:50:1};${line:51:22};${line:73:3};${line:76:6};${line:82:1};${line:83:15};${line:98:2};${line:100:2};"
         else
           newLine="${line:0:2};${line:2:7};${line:9:6};${line:14:106};"
         fi     
         sed -i -e "s/$line/$newLine/g" $newFileName
        done < $newFileName
```

The sed command returns error :
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'

Comment: In general, this means your line contains `/` characters. If there exists a different sigil that can't exist in your data, switch to it.

Comment: _However_, running a new copy of `sed` for every individual line you want to edit is crazy inefficient. Think about getting out of the business of using sed here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that you're using `/` as a sigil to separate arguments to the replace command in `sed`, but your data *contains* `/` characters. Using a different character (`s@old@new@`) is the quickest route to an immediate fix, if there exists a character you can be certain won't ever exist in your data.

The larger problem with this whole approach, though, is that running `sed` over and over (and over, and over) is going to be slower than just doing the edit in bash.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        62*) newLine="${line:0:2};${line:2:7};${line:9:12};${line:22:10};${line:32:16};${line:50:1};${line:51:22};${line:73:3};${line:76:6};${line:82:1};${line:83:15};${line:98:2};${line:100:2};"
        *)   newLine="${line:0:2};${line:2:7};${line:9:6};${line:14:106};"
    esac
    printf '%s\n' "$newLine"
done <"$origFileName" >"$newFileName"
```

That's not to say bash is a good tool for this job. If this were my code, I'd use awk (not bash starting awk over and over, but *just awk alone*).